# Percona-server-5.6.41 and sql_mode

Tags: percona-server, environment-variables

When setting

`sql_mode=""`

in  */etc/mysql/my.cnf*  server leaves this variable in it default value:

```
mysql> show variables like 'sql_mode';

+-------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+ 
| Variable_name | Value                                                                                 |
+-------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+ 
| sql_mode         | STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION  |
+-------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

However, if i set it manually in mysql shell:

`set global sql_mode="";`

server sets it as desired - to empty value. Till next server restart, when server sets this variable to default value again.

Tried in single and double quotes - no matter.
No errors in error log. No other default configuration files of mysql loaded
What's wrong?

Why?

Comment: In which section of the `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` file are you placing the `sql_mode` variable? Which Linux distro is this? Are you definitely 100% certain no other config files are being loaded? Are there no other .cnf files in `/etc/mysql/`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found: another MySQL config is `/usr/my.cnf` and it contains:

`sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES`

so, setting `sql_mode=""` did the thing I need.

Debian stretch. Percona server was installed after removing installed MySQL-5.6 community.

Intrecting thing: log doesn't mention this config for reading during server's startup...